# Cannot Query NULL or Empty Values in a Field or column in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query that is 99% working, but I cannot query `NULL` or empty records for

```
dbo.HUR_STAFF_DEMOGRAPHICS.DEMOGRAPHICS_POSITION = '' OR 
dbo.HUR_STAFF_DEMOGRAPHICS.DEMOGRAPHICS_POSITION IS NULL
```

I tried both, but the SQL statement below returns no rows if I add the lines above. However it DOES query rows for ALL staff that have a location and or position entered into the database, but my goal is to query this information for all staff that have a location and or position in the database, or if have a location and or position is NULL or BLANK (empty).

I queried the `Demographics` table alone, and I get a total of 1120 records, I also calculated the columns that have BLANK or `NULL` (so no position title or Location) and that is 316 records.

Sure enough, when I run this query I get 804 records returned, which means the query is not querying `Null` or empty columns for `Location` or `Position Title`.

Can anyone see why the query will not return the null columns?

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    dbo.HUR_STAFF_DEMOGRAPHICS.employee_no,
    first_name, last_name, PREFERRED_NAME,
    location,
    DEMOGRAPHICS_POSITION,
    EMPLOYEE_EMAIL,
    Location_name,
    Description
FROM
    dbo.HUR_STAFF_DEMOGRAPHICS,
    dbo.HUR_STAFF_INTERLINK,
    dbo.HUR_LOCATION,
    dbo.HUR_POSITION_CODE,
    dbo.HUR_EMAIL_ADDRESS
WHERE  
    dbo.HUR_STAFF_DEMOGRAPHICS.employee_no = dbo.HUR_STAFF_INTERLINK.employee_no
    AND dbo.HUR_STAFF_DEMOGRAPHICS.location = dbo.HUR_LOCATION.Location_no
    AND dbo.HUR_STAFF_DEMOGRAPHICS.DEMOGRAPHICS_POSITION = dbo.HUR_POSITION_CODE.POSITION_CODE
    AND dbo.HUR_STAFF_DEMOGRAPHICS.EMPLOYEE_NO = dbo.HUR_EMAIL_ADDRESS.EMPLOYEE_NO
    AND dbo.HUR_STAFF_DEMOGRAPHICS.employee_status = 'A'
    AND dbo.HUR_STAFF_DEMOGRAPHICS.DEMOGRAPHICS_POSITION IS NULL
ORDER BY 
    last_name
```

Thanks in advance for your time and expertise.

Comment: If no records are being returned, then those columns do not hold null or empty values OR your logic is flawed. Please provide a [mre] with sample data and desired results.

Comment: Let go of the old-style joins.   Explicit JOINS is the way to go

Comment: Your WHERE clause has `dbo.HUR_STAFF_DEMOGRAPHICS.DEMOGRAPHICS_POSITION = dbo.HUR_POSITION_CODE.POSITION_CODE` so `dbo.HUR_STAFF_DEMOGRAPHICS.DEMOGRAPHICS_POSITION is null` will never also be true.

Comment: @Dan Guzman, I'll be honest I'm struggling with this Query.  I have no doubt that your statement, is absolutely correct, but in all honesty, I don't know what to remove or add to fix it.  I'm also certain, that my old-style joins suck. I am not sure how to get the Position Description from Table dbo.HUR_POSITION_CODE.POSITION_CODE, while also getting the Empty or Null Full fields for the Position Description that is housed in that table, without that line....Can you provide some direction?

Comment: You need to provide the DDL for your tables (in the form of CREATE TABLE statements) and the DML to insert sample data, as well as the results you expect to obtain from that data. You can't expect us to help with a query without any data to use for testing solutions.

Comment: Hi Ken although I consider myself experienced in the IT Industry, I do not work with SQL all the time, can I extract the DDL from the SQL management tools for you?

Comment: Ideally you would have a [mre] as opposed to production schema/data.

Comment: Okay, Yeah this is all somewhat modified production data....let me see what I can come up with that is non-production.  I really appreciate all of your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your issue is that you are joining to the `DEMOGRAPHICS_POSITION` table on `DEMOGRAPHICS_POSITION = POSITION_CODE`, but are also looking for `DEMOGRAPHICS_POSITION = '' or DEMOGRAPHICS_POSITION = NULL` values. Assuming that the `DEMOGRAPHICS_POSITION` table has no empty code entry, the join to that table will fail for both of these conditions and no record will be returned.

The solution is to change that join to a `LEFT JOIN`, but the query must be first rewritten to use ANSI join syntax.

Using table aliases is also a good practice to simplify the statement and improve readability.

Try:

```
SELECT DISTINCT D.employee_no,
                first_name,
                last_name,
                PREFERRED_NAME,
                location,
                DEMOGRAPHICS_POSITION,
                EMPLOYEE_EMAIL,
                Location_name,
                Description
FROM HUR_STAFF_DEMOGRAPHICS D
JOIN HUR_STAFF_INTERLINK I
    ON D.employee_no = I.employee_no
JOIN HUR_LOCATION L
    ON D.location = L.Location_no
LEFT JOIN HUR_POSITION_CODE P
    ON D.DEMOGRAPHICS_POSITION = P.POSITION_CODE
JOIN HUR_EMAIL_ADDRESS E
    ON D.EMPLOYEE_NO = E.EMPLOYEE_NO
WHERE D.employee_status = 'A'
AND (D.DEMOGRAPHICS_POSITION = '' OR D.DEMOGRAPHICS_POSITION IS NULL)
ORDER  BY last_name
```

Alternately, for this particular usage, you can drop the `HUR_POSITION_CODE` join entirely, along with the corresponding select list references (Is that where `Description` comes from?)

Comment: `That you so much for your help!  I will try this.  And Yes, I'll have to look at the table again, but I *believe * the description is in the HUR_POSITION_CODE table. I was thinking I may need to re-write the query but wasn't sure how to go about that yet. Thank-you again for your input on this. Much appreciated. Trying it now.  I may have a few small questions still as I try this.

Comment: @T N  I feel like I'm close but with this reworked Query, which is BETTER and Cleaner than mine :)  I am getting the same result, as my query.  Basically, if I run your reworked query, with AND (D.DEMOGRAPHICS_POSITION = '' OR D.DEMOGRAPHICS_POSITION IS NULL),  I get the same result as my query, no errors, but I get NO data back. If I comment it out I get 804 records, that have location and position assigned, but the 316 records that have no location or position, are not included.  I really feel like we're close, but I'm missing something small, any insight?

Comment: HUR_Location = Which we are JOINING to HUR_STAFF_DEMOGRPHONCS will not have any Null Values as it is the Master LOCATION table that holds the ID or CODE for that location AND the location Description)
HUR_Position_code which is also connecting to HUR_staff_demographics is the master Position Code table that Holds the ID and CODE and the Position Description. 
HUR_staff_demographics holds all employees, but since they just started the Location and Position ID will be blank until assigned. Maybe I need them to assign those fields SOMETHING, and that will solve my issues.

Comment: Try two things: (1) change all of the `JOIN`s to `LEFT JOIN`s and rerun. There may be other blank/null lookup values that are causing the rows to be dropped. (2) Run the query `SELECT COUNT(*) AS N, DEMOGRAPHICS_POSITION, CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), DEMOGRAPHICS_POSITION) AS hex FROM HUR_STAFF_DEMOGRAPHICS GROUP BY DEMOGRAPHICS_POSITION ORDER BY DEMOGRAPHICS_POSITION`. This will summarize all of the values in use. If there are null or blank DEMOGRAPHICS_POSITION values present, they should be at the top. If you see something that looks blank, the hex representation might indicate otherwise.

Comment: That Worked! I added LEFT JOIN and I have ALL NULL records for Postion, and Locaiton and ALL POPULATED records for position and location!  Thank you SOOO much @T N!! :)